# Rotationally invariant maximally entangled states in higher dimensions

Tags: entanglement

Is there a straightforward generalization of the $\mathbb{C}^2$ Bell basis to $N$ dimensions? Is there a rotational invariant Bell state in higher dimensions? If yes, then what is the form of that state (*how does it look like*)? And, by rotational invariance, I mean that the state is invariant under applying the same unitary transformation $U$ to each qubit separately.

For example, $|\psi^-\rangle = \frac{|0\rangle|1\rangle -  |1\rangle|0\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{|\gamma\rangle|\gamma_\perp\rangle -  |\gamma_\perp\rangle|\gamma\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$, where $|\gamma\rangle$ is some quantum state in $\mathbb{C}^2$, and $|\gamma_\perp\rangle$ is orthogonal to $|\gamma\rangle$.

It would be helpful if I could see an example of the same, in say $\mathbb{C}^4$ space, perhaps in the computational basis {$|0\rangle, |1\rangle, |2\rangle, |3\rangle$} itself.

Answer (score 5):

An orthonormal maxinammly entangled basis for two quNits is easily defined:
$$
|\Psi_{xy}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\omega^{iy}|i,i+x\rangle,
$$
where $\omega$ is an $N$-th root of unity, and $x,y=0,1,\ldots,N-1$.

I don't believe that there is a rotationally invariant maximally entangled state, except in the case $N=2$. You may want to look up '[twirling](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9708015)', which almost does the calculation you need (they find states invariant under $U\otimes U^\star$ instead of $U\otimes U$), however the way that I convinced myself is the following:

- Any state invariant under $U\otimes U$ must be invariant under particular examples.
- Let's start with the $Z$-equivalent,
  $$
  \tilde Z=\sum_{n=1}^N\omega^n|n\rangle\langle n|
  $$
  The class of maximally entangled states that are invariant under this operation are
  $$
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}|n\rangle|N-1-n\rangle e^{i\phi_n},
  $$
  where we have free choice over the phases $\phi_n$.
- Next consider the action of the permutation operation
  $$
  P=\sum_{n=0}^{N-2}|n+1\rangle\langle n|+|0\rangle\langle N-1|
  $$
  For $N=2$, this maps back to the original state provided $e^{2i(\phi_2-\phi_1)}=1$. For all other $N$, we cannot map back to the original state. Terms like $|1\rangle|N-2\rangle$ become $|2\rangle|N-1\rangle$ which are not of the form $|m\rangle|N-1-m\rangle$, and are hence not in the original state.

Comment: The claim that there are no rotationally invariant maximally entangled states when $N\geq 3$ is correct. Density operators that are invariant under the action $\rho \mapsto (U\otimes U)\rho (U \otimes U)^{\dagger}$ are called Werner states, and they are never pure when $N\geq 3$.